# How to print all my log info in a file in java

Tags: java, logging, output, java.util.logging

From other sources i have read one way to do it by using logger

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
    FileHandler fh;  

    try {  

        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
        fh = new FileHandler("C:/temp/test/MyLogFile.log");  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

        // the following statement is used to log any messages  
        logger.info("My first log");  

    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    logger.info("Hi How r u?");  

}
```

In the above example, logger info is given as input by us. But how to print all the already existing warning info returned from my program to a output text file. I am able to print the console output given in my program to a file, while other warning info and log is printed in my console. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html#FileHandler(java.lang.String,%20boolean)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the other code most likely uses a different logger. With *java.util.logging* you can configure the root-logger right when the application starts and the other loggers will inherit the configuration.

```
private static void configureRootLogger() {
    try {
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("MyLogFile.log");
        fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

---

Full example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class LogToFileExample {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogA");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        configureRootLogger();
        logger.info("local test message");
        final LogTester tester = new LogTester();
        tester.logMessage();
    }

    private static void configureRootLogger() {
        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("MyLogFile.log");
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(fh);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warning("Could not add handler to log to file");
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LogTester {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogB");

    public void logMessage() {
        logger.info("external log message");
    }
}
```

Identical output in file and console:

```
May 28, 2021 9:44:50 AM org.testing.LogToFileExample main
INFO: local test message
May 28, 2021 9:44:50 AM org.testing.LogTester logMessage
INFO: external log message
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the statement e.printStackTrace(), let try a statement like this logger.log(Level.ALL, e.getMessage(), e) in your catch blocks.

For example,

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

...
    catch (SecurityException e) {  
                logger.log(Level.ALL, e.getMessage(), e);
                
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {  
                logger.log(Level.ALL, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

You also can try Log4J